# Scatter graph from excel data using c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js, import-from-excel

I would like to have a graph which is dynamic, so I choose c3.js. I am struck on how to import data from excel sheet and create a scatter graph for it  in c3.js. Please can any one help me in this?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to build dynamic scatter graph from excel sheet and then move on with it.

Comment: Everything is possible, but some things take too much time to develop.

Comment: ok fine. next is that how to fetch data from excel sheet. as we know data in the excel is in the form of tables that is rows and column. so now i have to make first row as x-axis and first column as y-axis. and their corresponding data should be plotted in the scatter graph.